# Removing from a list without affecting a dummy variable

Tags: python, list, loops, encryption, random

```
 from random import choice

inputs=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
func={}
code=""
z=len(inputs)
x=z-1
temp=inputs
while x>=0:
    y=choice(temp)
    print(str(x)+"   "+inputs[x]+"   "+y)
    func[inputs[x]]=y
    code=code+inputs[x]+y
    del temp[x]
    x=x-1
    print(temp)
    print(inputs)
```

Why does this code not asign every element of inputs to a unique and random element of inputs(as the temp dummy set)? it seems to delete items from both temp and inputs when only told to delete items from the dummy set.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `temp` and `inputs` are different names for the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not making a copy of 'inputs' when you do 'temp=inputs', but making a new variable to access the same content. If you want a new copy of the list, then use 'temp = inputs[:]'. Otherwise you are just creating a new reference to the same object, but not duplicating the object itself.

You can find more about this in the [official Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python).

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an alias of your list instead of a true copy of it:
replace `temp=inputs`  with   `temp=inputs[:]`

```
import random

inputs =  ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
func = {}
code = ""
z = len(inputs)
x = z-1
temp = inputs[:]    #<-- here
while x >= 0:
    y = random.choice(temp)
    print(str(x) + "   " + inputs[x] + "   " + y)
    func[inputs[x]] = y
    code = code+inputs[x] + y
    del temp[x]
    x = x - 1
    print(temp)
    print(inputs)
```